# How could you achieve this thick border in css?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css

Something in the lines of this

http://a.dryicons.com/images/icon_sets/colorful_stickers_part_2_icons_set/png/128x128/sterling_pound_currency_sign.png

I want the border to be around text, but also table cells like you were doing
a tic/tac/toe board

thanks

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include **attempted solutions**, **why they didn't work**, and the expected results.

Comment: You want a border around *text font* ?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/text-shadow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create several text-shadows. See this for example:

```
text-shadow: 3px 3px #F27405, -3px -3px #F27405, 3px -3px #F27405, -3px 3px #F27405;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U3Fkc/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/U3Fkc/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GGUYY/128/  thanks interesting stuff

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are showing there is a text-shadow.

```
#element {
color: yellow;
text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black; }
```

You could basically use that same code for your tic-tac-toe board. Hope that helps.

Comment: By the way, this question had been asked here and answered. I just can't add comment since I am under 50 points.